# Why does coverity flag a warning for this?

Tags: c, coverity

I am not sure why the static code analysis tool Coverity flags:

```
CID 40172 (#1 of 1): Parse warning (PW.INCOMPATIBLE_PARAM)
1. incompatible_param: argument of type "volatile mpls_RuntimeInfo_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *"
```

for this line:

```
memset(&SW_RuntimeInfo[idx],0,sizeof(mpls_RuntimeInfo_t));
```

when `SW_RuntimeInfo` is declared as `volatile static mpls_RuntimeInfo_t SW_RuntimeInfo[LABEL_T_CNT] = { 0 };` in the global scope. 
Why does it raise a flag & how do I fix this?

Comment: Never `memcpy` `volatile` qualified objects! `memcpy` does not guarantee any order of access. The question is **why** do you use `volatile` at all. It seems not to be a hardware register, so it is most likely wrong! (`volatile` is not suitable for inter-thread communication.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's throwing the warning because you're passing a volatile pointer to a non-volatile parameter. If you really want to just make the warning go away, just cast your argument to `void *`. But perhaps you should re-visit whether your variable should be volatile, or initialize it in a different manner.